# Translate compound word "airship" to Latin

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

Is there a more idiomatic way to translate "airship" than something like *navis aeris* (maybe this already is natural to a native speaker)? A compound word like "Airship" in English feels like a more distinct thing unto itself than saying "ship of the air". I am very much open to alternative nouns and phrasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The German–Latin dictionary *Neues Latein Lexikon*, 1998 edition, offers:

**aeronavis,** *is, f*

(Cited after the [Lexicon Latinum Hodiernum](http://www.lateinlexikon.com/lexicon_latinum_hodiernum_04_ijkl.pdf). The N.L.L. is supposed to be a translation of the Vatican's Italian–Latin *Lexicon Recentis Latinitatis*, infamous for its lengthy circumlocutions. The [online edition](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/rc_latinitas_20040601_lexicon_it.html) of the latters offers *aëria navis*, which is more in keeping with its reputation.)

On what reasoning I do not know. It cannot be a wealth of classical compounds beginning with *aero-*, because no such wealth exists.

Comment: I noticed in the L.L.H. they have also have _aeroplanum_. It would be interesting to know if there was any classical word which inspired these modern forms, but this still works fine for my needs either way.

Comment: Without the diaresis, it sounds like a bronze ship...